# initialize variables in TensorFlow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorboard

I'm starting an interactive session in TensorFlow, and after defining all the variables I'm starting to train end evaluate the network.

What is the difference between those two commands:

1. `tf.global_variables_initializer().run()`
2. `sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())`

till today I used the second command, but recently I noticed the first command.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two statements are equivalent: both [`tf.global_variables_initializer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/variable_helper_functions#global_variables_initializer) and [`tf.initialize_all_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/exporting_and_importing_meta_graphs#initialize_all_variables) return a `tf.Operation` that, when run, will initialize the global variables in a model. Passing an operation to `sess.run()` or calling `operation.run()` are equivalent when you have created a `tf.InteractiveSession`, or are in a `with tf.Session():` block.

The `tf.initialize_all_variables()` function has been deprecated (and will be removed from TensorFlow 1.0) because its name is confusing: it does not initialize *all* variables (i.e. local variables must be initialized separately, using `tf.local_variables_initializer()`), and it doesn't immediately initialize the variables (instead it returns an operation that you have to run yourself).